# How to use data from database for chart.js (bubble chart) with Ajax/JSON method?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, chart.js, bubble-chart

I would like to manipulate data from a database to use it with my bubble chart.

Here is what I did :

**1) A data.php file that puts the requested data in JSON format:**
​

```
<?php
/* data.php
 * Description : Retourne le score Page Speed, le score Yslow et le libelle du site depuis la BDD.*/
​
//Header > JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
​
//Connexion Base de donnée
include ("../inc/connexion_bd.inc.php");
​
//Requête
$query = sprintf("SELECT
    libelle_site,
    score_pagespeed,
    score_yslow
FROM
    sites
INNER JOIN ANALYSE ON ANALYSE
    .id_site = sites.id_site
INNER JOIN secteur_activite ON sites.id_secteur = secteur_activite.id_secteur
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT sites.id_site,
        MAX(date_analyse) AS last_analyse
    FROM
        sites
    INNER JOIN ANALYSE ON ANALYSE
    .id_site = sites.id_site
GROUP BY
    sites.id_site
) AS TEMP
ON
    TEMP.id_site = sites.id_site AND TEMP.last_analyse = ANALYSE.date_analyse
WHERE
    secteur_activite.id_secteur = 5");
​
//Execution rapide de la requête
$result = $bdd->query($query);
​
//Boucle pour chaques résultats
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
​
//Affichage du résultat
print json_encode($data);
```

**> Result in the console :** 
https://zupimages.net/up/18/26/6jwb.png

**2) A buble_db_php.js file that receives data from this page and creates the graph (Ajax) :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
​
    /**
     * Appel de la page data.php pour mettre les résultats de la BDD dans un tableau
     */
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/projets/Multi_Evaluation_Tool/api/data.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
​
            var site = {
                //Libelle du site
                label: [],
                //Score 1
                x: [],
                //Score 2
                y: []
            };
​
            var len = data.length;
​
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                site.label.push(data[i].libelle_site); //On place le libelle du site dans la variable site.label
                site.x.push(data[i].score_pagespeed); //On place le score PageSpeed du site dans la variable site.x
                site.y.push(data[i].score_yslow);      //On place le score Yslow du site dans la variable site.y
            }
​
            console.log(site);
​
            //On récupère l'ID du graphique (canvas) situé dans la page result.php (bubble chart)
            var ctx = $("#bubble-chart");
​
            //Configuration des données et des options du graphique
            var data = {
                labels: ["Rapport entre les scores"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: site.label, //Libelle du site
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,221,50,0.2)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(255,221,50,1)",
                        data: [{
                                x: site.x, //Score 1
                                y: site.y, //Score 2
                                r: 10
                            }]
                    }
                ]
            };
​
            var options = {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Rapport PageSpeed / Yslow'
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes:
                            [{
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        labelString: "Score 1"
                                    },
                                    ticks: {
                                        //Commencer à zéro ?
                                        beginAtZero: true,
                                        //Valeur maximum
                                        max: 100
                                    }
                                }],
                    xAxes:
                            [{
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        labelString: "Score 2"
                                    },
                                    ticks: {
                                        //Commencer à zéro ?
                                        beginAtZero: true,
                                        //Valeur maximum
                                        max: 100}
                                }]
                }
            };
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "bubble",
                //On appel les données et les options configurées :
                data: data,
                options: options
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**> Result in the console :**
https://zupimages.net/up/18/26/845x.png

My problem ? All results are put in a single "bubble", as if we wanted a bar finally, except that it is bubulles. So I see my mistake but do not know how to correct it, I have to make another loop to ** create a bubble by result **? How to proceed ?

**> My bubble chart, without bubles... :**
https://zupimages.net/up/18/26/i936.png

Thank you in advance for your time going on reading all this and trying to help me.

PS : Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Do you want to obtain one or more dataset?  As you mentioned, in order to assign `label`, `site.x`, and `site.y` you would have to put it inside a loop.  With that said, if you have multiple labels I would reckon you have multiple datasets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for reading ! I would like to have more dataset but I don't know how to do that. I have to write a look in "datasets: [ ]" ? @Koshux

Comment: One bubble represent one site with 2 data (2 results from my database like score_pagespeed, used for the x and score_yslow used for the y). So they will be lot of buble if there are lot of sites.

Comment: It really depends how you want to separate your data.  In the case of the example listed in this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-chartjs-pie-doughnut-and-bubble-charts--cms-28446), you may simple create multiple bubbles for one dataset.  I am assuming that is what you would like to achieve correct?  I can help you build an example via codepen in any case.

Comment: UP please ... :'(

I can now display the points but I can not manage to display 1 label (a site) by points, there are only the coordinates that work.

Link to result : https://zupimages.net/up/18/26/z9o3.png

Comment: I was working on an example but I found this instead, hope [this](https://jsfiddle.net/milostimotic/87msyj22/8/) helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know that I could do that like this, but my data are from a database and I have to order that with arrays..

Comment: With a functin I could have the x and y coordinations :             function generateData() {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                    results.push({
                        x: data[i].score_yslow,
                        y: data[i].score_pagespeed,
                        v: "10"
                    });
                }
                return results;
            } And I place "generateData()" in data and its work but all sites are "undefined"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thank you for your help !

> https://examples.lartak.fr/graphs/bulles

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var getSites = function () {

    var ctx = $("#bubble-chart");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/projets/Multi_Evaluation_Tool/api/data.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (results) {

            var dynamicColors = function () {
                var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
                var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
                var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
                return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
            };

            var sites = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                var site = {
                    label: results[i].libelle_site.toString(),
                    backgroundColor: dynamicColors(),
                    borderColor: "rgb(69,70,72)",
                    radius: 10,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    hoverRadius: 5,
                    data: [
                        {
                            x: Number(results[i].score_pagespeed),
                            y: Number(results[i].score_yslow),
                            r: 10
                        }
                    ]
                };
                sites.push(site);
                //console.log(sites);
            }
            console.log(sites);

            var data = {labels: ["Rapport entre les scores"], datasets: sites};
            var options = {
                title: {display: true, text: 'Rapport score PageSpeed / Indice'},
                scales: {
                    yAxes:
                            [
                                {
                                    scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: "Scores : Page Speed"},
                                    ticks: {beginAtZero: true, max: 100}
                                }
                            ],
                    xAxes:
                            [
                                {
                                    scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: "Indice"},
                                    ticks: {beginAtZero: true, max: 100}
                                }
                            ]
                }
            };
            new Chart(ctx, {type: "bubble", data: data, options: options});
        },
        error: function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
};
getSites();
```

});